# BlackBerry won't sync: Says Processing 

Tags: sync, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry Storm 2 and I have it set up to sync, just like I've done with all the other ones in the company.  They pull the address book/contacts from Outlook, and aren't synced to an Exchange Server.

I have everything setup and then when I hit synchronize it flashes *processing* the phone shows it trying to sync and then it is done in less than a second.

It did warn me that the computer was not supplying enough power to charge the device and it said that I should make sure the drivers are correct.

Also, I was warned that the device might not function properly down in the bottom right hand corner.  Any ideas?  I've uninstalled and reinstalled the BlackBerry software off the disc.

Comment: This is on topic - "except insofar as they interface with your computer" (from http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, download and install the latest BlackBerry Desktop Manager from blackberry.com.  This will also install the latest drivers for the RIM devices, which will presumably include the Storm 2.